# Is a contract verified and safe if it's created by a verified contract?

Tags: tokens, verify, contract-verification

The contract source code is not verified as you can see in the picture, but the contract was created by another contract code which is verified.

Does that mean that the contract code from the picture is also verified?
Can I trust that token?

[image]

EDIT:

Token address: https://etherscan.io/token/0x12b19d3e2ccc14da04fae33e63652ce469b3f2fd

Contract address: https://etherscan.io/address/0x12b19d3e2ccc14da04fae33e63652ce469b3f2fd

Deployer contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x94dc1cf66c8fd62ef3bd7da53f47423862839823

Comment: Bumping this question after adding the required contract addresses. I would be grateful if anyone could help me with my question.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "safe".

You can *confidently* derive the source code of this contract by the source code of the deployer. It will normally happen from a statement in the form of `new Contract(arguments)` and analysis of the deployer contract will leave no doubt about what it does.

It does not mean that the *quality* of the contract or the *intent* of the author is verified. This instance of the template is *as safe as* the original. If the author wishes to establish trust in the system, they will normally publish a publicly available third-party analysis of the code. This, so the individual isn't tasked with careful analysis of every possible scenario in every case.

You may get more precise advice if you copy the addresses in plain text so we can take a peek. It's not possible to do that from a picture without some pretty tedious manual work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rob. As you can see is the deployer contract verified, but the GRID contract address is not. The deployer address includes the GRID address under the tab "read" at "token". Does that bring any validity or safety or does that say nothing at all?

Comment: Also the GRID contract uses different arguments than the deployer contract right? Like total supply, token name or any function in the deployer could be disabled for the GRID token, correct?